# Tiptap with Bubble Menu Extension

Tags: javascript, laravel-livewire, tiptap

I am using Livewire/Alpinejs stack and have also installed tiptap editor. So far following this [link](https://www.tiptap.dev/installation/livewire) the editor works along with it's basic functionality/buttons. What I want is to add the Bubble Menu extension in the game. I have installed the package and also following the docs in this [link](https://www.tiptap.dev/api/extensions/bubble-menu) but it's not working (after selecting a word bubble menu wont appear). Here is the code below.

```js
import { Editor } from '@tiptap/core'
import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'
import BubbleMenu from '@tiptap/extension-bubble-menu'

window.setupEditor = function (content) {
  return {
    editor: null,
    content: content,

    init(element) {
      this.editor = new Editor({
        element: element,
        extensions: [
          StarterKit,
          BubbleMenu.configure({
            element: document.querySelector('#menu'),
          }),
        ],
        content: this.content,
        onUpdate: ({ editor }) => {
          this.content = editor.getHTML()
        }
      })

      this.$watch('content', (content) => {
        // If the new content matches TipTap's then we just skip.
        if (content === this.editor.getHTML()) return

        /*
          Otherwise, it means that a force external to TipTap
          is modifying the data on this Alpine component,
          which could be Livewire itself.
          In this case, we just need to update TipTap's
          content and we're good to do.
          For more information on the `setContent()` method, see:
            https://www.tiptap.dev/api/commands/set-content
        */
        this.editor.commands.setContent(content, false)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div
    x-data="setupEditor($wire.entangle('{{ $attributes->wire('model')->value() }}').defer)"
    x-init="() => init($refs.editor)"
    wire:ignore
    {{ $attributes->whereDoesntStartWith('wire:model') }}
>

    <template>
        <div id="menu">
            <div x-if="editor">
                <button @click="editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()" :class="{ 'is-active': editor.isActive('bold') }">
                    bold
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <div x-ref="editor"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I needed to change and put the id to the parent element (template).

```
<template x-if="editor" id="menu">
    <div>
        <div>
            <button @click="editor.chain().focus().toggleBold().run()" :class="{ 'is-active': editor.isActive('bold') }">
                bold
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```